# Compute the limit for a harmonic function given two known limits

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

This problem is from a set of exercises that I have. It states:

> Let $u\in C(\overline{\mathbb{R}_+^2})$ be a bounded harmonic function in the upper half plane $\mathbb{R}_+^2$, satisfying $u(x,0) \to \pi$ as $x\to \infty$ and $u(x,0)\to 0$ as $x \to -\infty$. Compute the limit of $u(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$ as $r\to\infty$ for each $0<\theta < \pi$.

I tried using the Poisson formula for the half plane but didn't manage to get anywhere. I appreciate any input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Suppose $u(t,0)\to 0$ as $|t|\to \infty,$ with the  other hypotheses unchanged. Let $v(z) = u(-1/z).$ Show $v$ is continuous at the origin, with value $0$ there. Show that this implies $\lim_{r\to \infty} u(re^{it})=0$ for all $t\in (0,\pi).$ Now to the original problem: There is an easy bounded harmonic function $u_0$ that equals $\pi$ on the positive real axis and $0$ on the negative real axis. Given $u$ as in your problem, apply the above to $u-u_0.$

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I tried your approach unfortunately am still getting stuck. I know that showing that $v$ is continuous (and equal to 0) at the origin is equivalent to showing that $\lim_{r\to\infty} u(re^{it}) = 0$ for all $0\leq t\leq \pi$. Do you have another hint about how to prove that?

Comment: Actually that's not an equivalence, it's a $\implies$ To show the result about $v,$ recall that $v=P[v|_{\mathbb R}].$ And if the boundary function has a point of continuity on the line, then so does $v$ in the upper half plane.

Comment: Suppose a function $w$ is bounded and harmonic in the half plane $\mathbb{R}^2_+$. If $w$ is continuous up to the boundary then I can prove that $w$ is given by the Poisson formula. How can I prove this before showing continuity?

Comment: Things clicking better now?

Comment: Yes. Thank you :-)